# Rapid transfer of binary files

Tags: tcp, webserver, http2, nw.js, quic

We have a daily need to ship about 500 MB of compressed image files (about 280K each).

Currently we do this the fast easy way. A web server, and downloads via http.

We are now looking at the putting a better client (nw.js) on the client side. So we have the opportunity to improve the transport protocol.

Data flows only one way.

We have a couple of thoughts but I would love to hear better ideas.

1. Using a HTTP2 (SPDY) compliant server, and the Chromium hooks in
   nw.js for HTTP2 receiving
2. Using a TCP connection (custom node.js server -> node code in nw.js)
3. Perhaps we should look at QUIC: https://www.chromium.org/quic
4. Would bundling this into a zip file (which would not decrease bytecount, since it is already compressed) help?
5. What does oneDrive, GoogleDrive, and dropbox do in these cases?

Any thoughts?

Has anyone tried ASPERA: http://asperasoft.com/software/transfer-clients/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 systems can take advanatge of "TCP Fast Open" technology which you can read about here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Fast_Open

To enable this technology, Chromium accepts this parameter:

> --enable-tcp-fastopen

From what I've read this only works in Windows 10 but I've no idea about other platforms. Good luck.